# 「その他の方法でツイートを共有」にリストされるアプリを追加・削除するには？

Tags: java, ios, android, twitter, mobile

Twitterでツイートの右下にあるアイコンを押すと
「その他の方法でツイートを共有」というメニューがあります。

PCのブラウザでTwitterを見ているときは「その他の方法でツイートを共有」を選んでも何も起こりません。

スマホのブラウザでTwitterを見ているときは「その他の方法でツイートを共有」で
・SMS
・Gmail
・Line
など10種類ほどのアイコンが表示されます。

PC版では何も起こらないのは仕様でしょうか？
設定によっては「その他の方法でツイートを共有」でGmailが起動するようにしたりできるのでしょうか？

スマホで「その他の方法でツイートを共有」のときに表示されるアプリのリストはどのような基準で選ばれているのでしょうか？
このリストに自作のアプリを表示させたいです。

おそらくTwitter側の設定ではなく、スマホ側の設定な気がするのですが、定かではありません。

Answer (score 1):

> 「その他の方法でツイートを共有」というメニューがあります。

Twitter Web App(ブラウザでのTwitter)において、この項目は[Web Share API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share)をりようしています。

> PC版では何も起こらないのは仕様でしょうか？

この項目はWebShare APIがサポートされていない環境では表示されないようになっています。
現時点でPCで対応しているのはChrome(Win10/ChromeOSのみ)、Edge、Safari(macOS)です。モバイルの各種ブラウザもまた大抵対応しました。

各OSに準じた共有画面が表示される筈です。(ただし手元でもうまく表示されない場合があることが確認できました。OS側の問題？) 例えばWindowsであれば以下のような。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

まあ、現状のWindowsでは近距離共有やUWPが現状メインのようなところがあるので正直使い物になるかはわかりません。Windowsでは`DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI`が使われているはずですがその制約かな…

姉妹APIとして[Web Share Target API](https://web.dev/web-share-target/)が存在します。これはPWAとしてインストールしたアプリを共有インテントの送信先として登録させる機能を持つAPIです。これがWindowsでも使えるようになれば御の字なのですが、おそらく前述の事情もあってか現状で使えるのはAndroidとChrome OSのみのようです。

> スマホのブラウザでTwitterを見ているときは...

スマホアプリであれば共有インテントの設定されているアプリ([Android](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)/[iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html))であれば共有先にできるはずです。また、Webアプリであれば前述のようにWebShare Target APIが利用できます。

…ただおそらく質問の意図はそういうことではなくAndroidのChromeで少し前(Chrome 85)に変更された[新しい共有ダイアログ](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/08/26/chrome-85-enables-64-bit-support-on-android-10-replaces-the-share-sheet-and-more-apk-download/)でしょうか。
普段使うアプリが出るわけでもなく不便な部分もあるので気にはなっていたのですが私は調べられていません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: Web Share API
・Twitter側で使っている機能
・共有先のアプリリストを表示する

Web Share Target API
・自作アプリ側で使うべき機能
・共有先のアプリリストに自作アプリを追加する

ということですよね。
あの機能の呼び名が分からず躓いていたのですが、キーワードが分かったのでだいぶ調べやすくなります。